# Trying to remove rows based in csv file based off column value

Tags: python, csv, duplicates

I'm trying to remove duplicated rows in a csv file based on if a column has a unique value. My code looks like this:

```
seen = set()
for line in fileinput.FileInput('DBA.csv', inplace=1):
    if line[2] in seen:
        continue # skip duplicated line
    seen.add(line[2])
    print(line, end='')
```

I'm trying to get the value of the 2 index column in every row and check if it's unique. But for some reason my seen set looks like this:

```
{'b', '"', 't', '/', 'k'}
```

Any advice on where my logic is flawed?

Comment: The line is iterable by characters, not by fields.  To work with fields, you'll want to use a `csv.reader`, not `fileinput`.

Comment: To my understanding fileinput allows me to edit the file inplace. Is that possible for csv.reader as well?

Comment: @Rainoa Pretty sure that `fileinput` just creates an in-memory backup to "modify in place". You can do that manually. It's main use-case is working with *multiple files*, but with a single file, this is pretty straightforward.

Comment: No, `fileinput` is utilized to iterate over multiple similar files in a directory, although singular files are accepted. The method reads lines as text by default, so the `line [2]` call is giving you the second character in the line string. You'd have to call `line.split (",")[2]` to get the third value, again, still as a string.

Comment: Don't use `line.split(",")`.  This approach is broken, you must take into account csv quoting.

Comment: Would i be able to do csv.reader('DBA.csv', 'rw') for reading and writing to the same file? I'm not sure how to get around editing file inplace with csv.reader

Comment: I've made `line.split ()` work with reading textual csv lines. I just asserted what type is what for a known csv structure.

Answer (score 0):

You're reading your file line by line, so when you pick `line[2]` you're actually picking the third character of each line you're running this on.

If you want to capture the value of the second column for each row, you need to parse your CSV first, something like:

```
import csv

seen = set()
with open("DBA.csv", "rUb") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for line in reader:
        if line[2] in seen:
            continue
        seen.add(line[2])
        print(line)  # this will NOT print valid CSV, it will print Python list
```

If you want to edit your CSV in place I'm afraid it will be a bit more complicated than that. If your CSV is not huge, you can load it in memory, truncate it and then write down your lines:

```
import csv

seen = set()
with open("DBA.csv", "rUb+") as f:
    handler = csv.reader(f)
    data = list(handler)
    f.seek(0)
    f.truncate()
    handler = csv.writer(f)
    for line in data:
        if line[2] in seen:
            continue
        seen.add(line[2])
        handler.writerow(line)
```

Otherwise you'll have to read your file line by line and use a buffer that you'll pass to `csv.reader()` to parse it, check the value of its third column and if not seen write the line to the live-editing file. If seen, you'll have to seek back to the previous line beginning before writing the next line etc.

Of course, you don't need to use the `csv` module if you know your line structures well which can simplify the things (you won't need to deal with passing buffers left and right), but for a universal solution it's highly advisable to let the `csv` module do your bidding.